# Swift 3 - Segue / Cast from uiviewcontroller to unrelated type always fails

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to pass a boolean statement from my viewcontroller managing viewcontroller to another one using a segue and I am getting "cast from uiviewcontroller to unrelated type always fails" error.

**mainVC**

```
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
        guard let viewControllerIndex = theViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

        if(viewControllerIndex == 0){
            let sessionTimerActive: Bool = false
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "sessionActiveBool", sender: sessionTimerActive)

        }
```

**secondVC**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let sessionTrackerBoolClone = segue.destination as? Bool{
    sesssionTrackerActive = sessionTrackerBoolClone
    }
}
```

However in line

```
if let sessionTrackerBoolClone = segue.destination as? Bool{
```

I am getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to type cast `sender` to get your `Boolean` value not the `segue.destination` because destination is type of `UIViewController`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let sessionTrackerBoolClone = sender as? Bool{
        sesssionTrackerActive = sessionTrackerBoolClone
    }
}
```

If you want to pass this Bool value to your next controller then type cast the `destination` to your `ViewController` and set its property.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController //Your ViewController class
    if let sessionTrackerBoolClone = sender as? Bool{
        vc.sesssionTrackerActive = sessionTrackerBoolClone
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `segue.destination` is going to be a `UIViewController`. So why are you casting that to `Bool`? It is that cast that gives you an error. You might be looking at the wrong value there. Fix that and you should be fine :)